# Why 2^31 can't store in integer variable but - 2^31 can?

Tags: java, c++

Integer variables are 4-bytes or 32-bits, and 2^31 and -2^31 both in binary numbers are 32 bits. But when you put 2^31 = 2,147,483,648 in an integer variable it shows an error, but for -2^31 it is ok. Why?

[image]

Comment: Because you need to put the 0 somewhere

Comment: Yes,  the positive range starts from 0

Comment: Hint: it's easier to reason about this with small numbers. 8 bits can store -128 to 127 inclusive, for a total of 256 values.

Comment: Another hint: The most significant (highest) bit is a *sign* bit (in 2's complement notation). When that is set, the number is negative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Integer variables are 4-bytes or 32-bits, and 2^31 and -2^31 both in binary numbers are 32 bits

No they are not.

in basic binary, negative numbers aren't a thing. We have zeroes and ones. There is no - sign.

In binary, `2^31` becomes:

`1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`

In binary, -2^31 cannot be represented without first defining how negative numbers are to be stored.

Commonly (and java does this too), a system called 2's complement is used. 2's complement sounds real complicated: Take the number, say, 5. Represent it in binary (for this exercise, let's go with byte, i.e. 8  bits): `0000 0101`. Now, flip all bits: `1111 1010`, and then add 1: `1111 1011`.

That is -5 in signed 2's complement binary.

This bizarre system has two amazing properties: Math continues to work as normal without needing to know if the number is signed or unsigned. Let's try it. -5 + 2 is -3, right? let's see.. what's `1111 1011` + `0000 0010`? Without worrying about 2's complement at all, I get `1111 1101`. Let's apply 2's complement conversion: first flip the bits: `0000 0010`, then add 1: `0000 0011`, which is... 3. So `-5 + 2` is -3. Check. The other amazing property is that it doesn't 'waste' 2 of the `2^32` "slots" on zeroes. Let's try the 2's complement of 0: `0000 0000`, then flip all bits: `1111 1111`, then add 1: `0000 0000` (with a bit overflow that we ignore). That's nice: 0 is its own 2's complement. We can't tell 0 and -0 apart, but that's generally a good thing.

Another property of this system is that the first bit is the 'sign' bit. if it is 1, it is negative, if 0, it is not.

Let's try to 2's complement `1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`. First, flip the bits: `0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111`. Then add 1: `1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`. Wait. That's... what we had!!

Yup. and because the first bit is negative, `1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000` is NEGATIVE.

Perhaps you are forgetting that 0 is a thing, and 0 is neither positive nor negative.

So, if 0 needs to be representable, and gets a 0 sign bit (zero in bits is 0000000... of course), that means the 'space' in the half of all representable numbers that start with a 0 is now one smaller, because 0 has eaten one slot. That means there is one more negative number representable vs. the positive numbers. (or, alternatively, that 0 'counts' as positive, therefore 0 is the first positive number, but -1 is the first negative number). Therefore, there must be at least 1 negative number that has no positive equivalent in 2's complement. That number is... 2^31. `-2^31` fits in 32-bit signed. `+2^31` doesn't.

Let's imagine a 3-bit signed number, with 2's complement. We can list them all:

```
000 = 0
001 = 1
010 = 2
011 = 3
100 = -4
101 = -3
110 = -2
111 = -1
```

Note how -4 is in there, but +4 is not, and note how we covered 8 numbers. `2^3 = 8` - 3 bits can represent 8 numbers, not more than that.

Answer (score 1):

From the [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html#:%7E:text=int%3A%20By%20default%2C%20the%20int,value%20of%20232%2D1.) we got that:

> int: By default, the int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer, which has a minimum value of -2^31 and a maximum value of 2^31-1. In Java SE 8 and later, you can use the int data type to represent an unsigned 32-bit integer, which has a minimum value of 0 and a maximum value of 2^32-1. Use the Integer class to use int data type as an unsigned integer. See the section The Number Classes for more information. Static methods like compareUnsigned, divideUnsigned etc have been added to the Integer class to support the arithmetic operations for unsigned integers.

From another [document(simple and quite understandable)](https://www.javamex.com/java_equivalents/unsigned.shtml#:%7E:text=When%20an%20integer%20is%20signed,are%20signed%20(except%20char).) we got:

> When an integer is signed, one of its bits becomes the sign bit, meaning that the maximum magnitude of the number is halved. (So an unsigned 32-bit int can store up to 2^32-1, whereas its signed counterpart has a maximum positive value of 2^31-1.)

> In Java, all integer types are signed (except char).

Is because the first bit indicate the sign bit. Maximum positive value it can store it `2^31 - 1`. There are many resources available for this.